# How to jump to first uncommented out statement in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, ide, comments

I'm using `/print` to search for my uncommented-out `print` statements as I want to comment them out. I know I could use search and replace to first remove all the comments, and then apply them, but I simply want to find the next uncommented out print statement, and I can't work out how to.

E.g. I have :

```
    #print fooVal
        #... do stuff
        #print barF
        #... more stuff
            print gold # <-- I want to use vim to jump straight to this line
```

I want to match this so I don't have to cycle through *all* the `print` statements (even the commented-out ones) just to find the *one* `print` statement that is without `#`.

I've tried using `:s/^\s+print` and `/^print` but [vim](http://www.vim.org/) does not like it. Also, I looked [here](http://www.vimregex.com/), but I could not find the info.

Comment: What's wrong with `/^print`? It works fine for me. Also if you want to use `+` operator you need to escape it: `/^\s\+print`

Comment: `+` operator is not supported in vim regex. However `/^print` works fine and if you want to take blank spaces into account `/^\s*print` should work.

Comment: regexp `+` can be used as `\+` in vim, see my description below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case no spaces before print. So try to use '*' instead of '+'.

This works for me: `/^\s*print`

Less convenient pattern should highlight uncommented lines with print: `/^[^#]*\s*print`

Answer (score 1):

In your case @Taky's solution is the best I think, but I noticed some comments on vim's regexp. I've studied this the last days, so perhaps it's a good idea to write it down.

In vimworld the use of e.g. `*`, `^` and `$` as regexp special characters is called "magic" (`set magic` is default). As default `+` is not a regexp character and has to be used as `\+` to mean "regexp +". However with small changes it can be "magic" too, read this: [vim help - search patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_27.html) (the same as in vim editor, but as HTML, and with a good search function at the top).
See also [vim help - pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html)

Here is a little short guide (rules are overruling down the list):
**settings:**
`:set ignorecase` to ignore case in search and replace,
`:set smartcase` for ignoring case as long as no upper case letter is used (`ignorecase` must be on for it to work).
`:set magic` to be able to use some characters as regexp special characters, e.g. `*`, without having to precede them with `\`. This is default (I think).

**Rules in search pattern** (overrules settings)
`\c` ignore case, `\C` case sensitive
Use as e.g. `/\cxxx` for "ignore case", `/\Cxxx` for case sensitive (`\c` is the same as flag `i` in replace syntax as `s/xxx/yyy/i`.
`\m` use "magic" (same as setting `magic`), `\M` no "magic".

Here is the **interesting part, to use `+` in vim patterns**:
`\v` described as "very magic", that is what we all are used to when using regexp I think.
`\V` "very nomagic", ALL is literal, only `\` has a special meaning.

Now, **`+` can be used directly** as in `/\v\s+print` (but for you it's better to use `*` in that particular case, `+` won't find "plugin" that starts the line).
E.g. also `{` expressions must have `\` if `\v` isn't used.

**Tip:** do these mappings in .vimrc to always use `\v` in search patterns:

```
" To get 'normal' behavior for regexps (use "\V" to avoid)
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
```

(And it's very easy to just "backspace" away the `\v`when it's unwanted).